# NSLocalizedString doesn't work inside drawRect:

Tags: swift, drawrect, localizable.strings

`drawText(text:inRect)` is my custom method to draw text in rect.

Inside my `Localisable.strings` there is a line:

```
"No data" = "No data to draw the graph";
```

1. `drawText("No data", inRect: CGRectMake(0, rect.height/2, rect.width, 20))` draws `"No data"`
2. `drawText(NSLocalizedString("No data wrong", comment: ""), inRect: CGRectMake(0, rect.height/2, rect.width, 20))` draws `"No data wrong"`
3. `drawText(NSLocalizedString("No data", comment: ""), inRect: CGRectMake(0, rect.height/2, rect.width, 20))` draws **nothing!!!**

Why?

My localisable strings are working, but not here inside the method: `drawRect(rect:)`

What is more interesting, when I print at that time on console:

```
po NSLocalizedString("No data", comment: "")
```

I get: `No data to draw the graph`. So it is working, but it is not drown

Comment: Test `drawText("No data to draw the graph", inRect: CGRectMake(0, rect.height/2, rect.width, 20))`. I assume that the text length exceeds the CGRect width and your custom `drawText` draws nothing.

Comment: With your `po NSLocalizedString(...)` you made sure that `NSLocalizedString` works as expected.

Comment: You were right, the text was too long...